# How do I Link a .pdf document in the Applet table column

Tags: java, applet

I wanted to link a .pdf file to an Applet

I am using the following code

```
try {


 //if (column == docColId) {

String doccolvalue = this.getTable().getValueAt(row,
   column).toString();

String lPathPrefix = "gopher://muceap10.muc.amadeus.net/User Step Folders/BPS_Files/Outlooksoft CPM/01 - Production Environment/01 -
   Documentation Library/01 -
   Documents/Daily_Checks/";

String lPath = (lPathPrefix + doccolvalue).replace(" ", "%20");
 URI lURI = new URI(lPath);
 //lPathPrefix = lPathPrefix.replace(" ", "%20");
  //URI lURI = new URI(lPathPrefix + doccolvalue);
   java.awt.Desktop lDesktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
   lDesktop.open(new File(lURI));

   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

But I am getting the following error

```
URI scheme is not "file"
 at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at client.cpm.dailyT0.CBRCPMDailyT0View.table_mouseClicked(CBRCPMDailyT0View.java:371)
 at client.cpm.dailyT0.CBRCPMDailyT0View.access$1(CBRCPMDailyT0View.java:325)
```

Can any one help me ,

Thank in Advance.

Comment: please use code(101) button to write code. Does java understand "gopher://" protocol?

Answer (score 0):

In absence of full code I tried using this...

```
import java.net.URI;

public class SimpleTableDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String lPathPrefix = "gopher://muceap10.muc.amadeus.net/User Step Folders/BPS_Files/Outlooksoft CPM/01 - Production Environment/01 -  Documentation Library/01 -"+
        "Documents/Daily_Checks/";

        String lPath = (lPathPrefix + "test").replace(" ", "%20");
        URI lURI = new URI(lPath);

        System.err.println(lURI);
    }
}
```

And it seems it is working ...

**Output**

`gopher://muceap10.muc.amadeus.net/User%20Step%20Folders/BPS_Files/Outlooksoft%20CPM/01%20-%20Production%20Environment/01%20-%20%20Documentation%20Library/01%20-Documents/Daily_Checks/test`

Post full snippet if possible....